# Spring: populate an OAuth2 form without opening a browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm having a OAuth2 application.
To test the backend service, I would like a test user to be logged on programmatically and query then the API, asserting the response.

In others words, I'm trying to do the following (apache http) but with Spring:

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "https://foo/authsvc?PolicyId=urn:bar:security:authentication:asf:nidlogin&Target=https://foo/mga/sps/auth");
    java.util.List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "john"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "doe"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operation", "verify"));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));

    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

**Question**

How can this be done with Spring ?

EDIT

I don't want to Mock the OAUth authentication.

After the OAuth, some accounts must be selected programmatically (checkbox) as well as clicking the submit button, this still, without opening a browser.

Comment: So you want to automate your frontend tests? If so you should check out selenium (https://www.seleniumhq.org). While it would also be possible to change the login flow  for the tests as Matt suggested I don't think that's preferable as you should include the authentication workflow into the tests.

Comment: @BeWu Thanks the suggestion. I'm aware of tools such as Selenium, Proractor, etc. But the idea here is to unit test the backend API: logon transparently, then query the API and assert the response. Clarified the question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you use authentication code grant and you want to continue using that for the tests you will need someone typing in a password either human or tool. The only other way I know is using the implicit grant as Matt suggested.

Comment: @BeWu I can do it successfully (login, select a checkbox after login and submit the form) with Apache HTTP. I then get the token back from the OAuth server that I can use to invoke the backend API that I want to test. I just try to do the same with Spring. So I hopes Spring offer a way to do it as well

Answer (score 0):

You could use the password flow for testing. This flow doesn't require a browser. See:  [OAuth RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3).

Example:

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w
```

Edit:

If you want to test your login flow you could use MockMvc. (https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web)

Example:

```
@Before
public final void init() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
            .build();
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    ...

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(
            post("/login")
                    .content(...)
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have clarify the question. I'm not looking for the RFC but how to implement it :)

Comment: I have extended my answer. (However, in my opinion, using the password flow for all other endpoint tests is still appropriate.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately, mocking the authentication won't provide me with the token I need to the the backend API. So in my use case, I can't mock. I'm not trying here to test the OAuth layer but the backend.